# Control Height of <li> in IE 7

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I have a menu built with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I want to have small separators between sections. For the separators, I just set a background color and a short height on an `<li>`. Looks very nice... except in IE7 where the `<li>` seems to refuse to change its height to be shorter than all the other `<li>`s in the same `<ul>`. I have tried different ways of affecting the height of the separator `<li>` (height, line-height, font-size) with no success.

I have a fix that will leave the separator height as is and color the whole background in IE 7, but that is not really the appearance I want (the separator is too big). Can anyone think of another way to control the height of an `<li>` tag?

Here is a sample - in IE8 toggling compatibility view will show the problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu {
    width:100px;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style-type:none; 
    border-top: solid 1px red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.menu ul li {
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.menu ul li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu ul li.separator {
    height:4px;
    background-color:red;
}

</style>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="separator"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that ie6/ie7 will expand an empty element to the height of your font.  You can get around this by adding `font-size:0` and `line-height:0` to `.menu ul li.separator`.

A better solution would be to add a thicker bottom border to the `<li>` that is before the separator.

```
.menu ul li.sep {border-bottom-width:6px}

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="sep"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: My first post on stackoverflow, and I am amazed by the number of responses I received so quickly! Thanx to Emily for the solution - setting both font-size and line-height to 0 was the fix (I had tried both separately, but not together). Also, Emily's second suggestion was also excellent - however, my menus are dynamically generated, so I may not be able to use it.

Comment: `font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px` fixes this nightmare with <li> element height in IE7. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set your css for the LI to `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try setting your `li` as follows:

```
li{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   height:myHeight;
   clear:right;//may be necessary, can't check with IE7
}
```

This is what I've done with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `line-height` attribute to `.menu ul li`?

Else have you tried using horizontal rule `<hr>` as a separator instead? If you're using horizontal rule, you can set the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `0px` and see what happens. Can't guarantee it looks the same on IE and other browsers, but at least you tried. =)

Comment: I did try a horizontal rule, but the appearance in this case was not what I was looking for. However, I am going to play with it some more and see if it will work in other designs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daniel A. White answer you can experiment with line-height to center your text vertically and create the necessary height.

Answer (score 0):

Do what was suggested in the previous posts. If these changes are causing issues in browsers other than IE, you can do the following to have only IE use them:

```
.selector {
    prop1 : val1; /* default value for all browsers */
    *prop1 : val2; /* only IE will pick this one up and it will override the initial value of prop1. */
}
```

This works much better than trying to do special commenting to include separate style sheets, etc.